# Please clarify the link in the Stack Exchange UI that goes to your profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, user-interface

It's entirely possible I'm the only person on earth who didn't realise this:

[image: UI Bar]

That "logged in" part is actually an active area.

To me, despite the fact it looks visually the same as all the other links, the writing itself doesn't convey that it does anything.

It looks for all the world like redundant informational data that is just dead information¹.

I would have known it meant something if it said "My Profile", or even just "Profile". Perhaps my user name would work there too, because that's what the rest of the Stack Exchange Sites do, and it would be at least consistent enough to raise the **suspicion** that it does something instead of passing me over.

Sure, now that I've worked it out, I know, and everyone who reads this will know, but for everyone else, it might be a little more fumbling around in the dark until you get lucky, and that's a little like mystery meat navigation =).

¹ Much like half this sentence =).

Comment: Hmm, it actually shows my username there to me. Either this is the most quickly implemented `[feature-request]` ever, or there's something else at play here, heh.

Comment: @Tim : Weird O_o, still not doing it for me.

Comment: Logged out, logged in again, still doing it.

Comment: I have a username there as well. The wrong username (My SO one), but a username nonetheless. Does it give Kent Fredric as your username in the resulting profile page?

Comment: @Grace it does. Stack Exchange is the only site I've hit so far with this issue :/

Comment: Hm... do you have any tag sets setup? Have you ever had any? I know a few months ago I had "logged in" shown up there as well, I'm wondering if maybe you need some kind of interaction, maybe, to get your username to display. This is a horribly out-there offshot, though.

Comment: I've had subscriptions to tags and stuff, but cancelled them, but even when I had them, there was no copy of my name up there.

Comment: I think this probably should be more a "bug" than a feature-request then.

Comment: Just futzed with tagsets, no change.

Comment: I think Jeff just hates me specifically ;)

Comment: @Kent - Well in that case he hates me too! :)

Answer (score 2):

This link is now your name when logged in - like all other Stack Exchange 2.0 sites.